# Woocommerce Orders, Products and Customers API Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, wordpress, woocommerce

I've been trying to synchronize my WooCommerce products, orders and customers with Laravel using this package, aiming to ensure seamless integration of products, orders, and customer data.

> composer require automattic/woocommerce

The package functions smoothly when retrieving Products or Orders.

**Here is the sample code.**

This code successfully retrieves Orders, but it imposes a limit of 100 items. If there are more than 100 items, I'm unable to fetch them. Is there a method to overcome this limitation? I've attempted to obtain the total number of orders/products for pagination purposes, but unfortunately, I'm unable to retrieve even the total count.

```
$since_id = 0;
$url            =   $this->store['store_url'];
$consumer_key   =   $this->store['consumer_key'];
$consumer_secret=   $this->store['consumer_secret'];
$options        =   [ 'wp_api' => true, 'version' => 'wc/v3' ];
$woocommerce    =   new Client($url, $consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $options);

$page = 1;
$per_page = 100; // Set a reasonable limit to avoid overloading
$limit = 10000;
$all_orders = [];
do {
    $args = [
        'per_page' => $per_page,
        'page' => $page,
    ];
    $orders = $woocommerce->get('orders', $args);
    $all_orders = array_merge($all_orders, $orders);
    // Check if there are more orders:
    $has_more = isset($orders['headers']['x-wp-totalpages']) && $page < $orders['headers']['x-wp-totalpages'];
    $page++;
} while (count($orders) >= $per_page);
```

This code is returning an empty array from WooCommerce. The problem seems to be specific to customers, as it's not retrieving any data; only an empty array is returned.

```
$url            =   $this->store['store_url'];
$consumer_key   =   $this->store['consumer_key'];
$consumer_secret=   $this->store['consumer_secret'];
$options        =   [ 'wp_api' => true, 'version' => 'wc/v3' ];

$woocommerce = new Client($url, $consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $options);
$args = [
  'per_page' => $per_page,
  'page' => $page,
];
$customers = $woocommerce->get('customers', $args);
$all_customers = array_merge($all_customers, $customers);
```

Here are the responses I'm receiving from WooCommerce:
[image]

Comment: What's the context of this code, where does `$per_page` get its value set?

Answer (score 0):

removed this check condition

```
$has_more = isset($orders['headers']['x-wp-totalpages']) && $page < $orders['headers']['x-wp-totalpages'];
```

because until the condition based on the number of fetched orders per page is no longer met, the loop already keeps retrieving orders. Try this code:

```
$url = $this->store['store_url'];
$consumer_key = $this->store['consumer_key'];
$consumer_secret = $this->store['consumer_secret'];
$options = ['wp_api' => true, 'version' => 'wc/v3'];

$woocommerce = new Client($url, $consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $options);

$page = 1;
$per_page = 100;

$all_orders = [];

do {
    $args = [
        'per_page' => $per_page,
        'page' => $page,
    ];
    $orders = $woocommerce->get('orders', $args);

    $all_orders = array_merge($all_orders, $orders);

    $page++;

} while (count($orders) >= $per_page);
```

Comment: thank you mate, now i'm able to get all the orders and products more then 100, it worked, but i'm not getting customers. is there any way to debug or check? you can also see the screenshot i have shared and code snippet for getting customers

Comment: @Taranjeet Singh it has worked, now if you can please check customers call its not returning any data, what are the possibilities?

Comment: @SalmanKhanSohoo do you want to retrieve data inside this code?
try this and let me know if you need any help in this.
 `$woocommerce->get('customers', $args);`

Comment: @TaranjeetSingh yes you can see the screenshot the response and also you can see this paragraph in the question "This code is returning an empty array from WooCommerce. The problem seems to be specific to customers, as it's not retrieving any data; only an empty array is returned."

Comment: @SalmanKhanSohoo try to code with add check condition  

`$per_page = 100;
$page = 1;
$args = [ 'per_page' => $per_page, 'page' => $page,];
$customers = $woocommerce->get('customers', $args);
 if (!empty($customers)) {
      $all_customers = array_merge($all_customers, $customers);
      while (count($customers) === $per_page) {
        $page++;
            $args['page'] = $page;
            $customers = $woocommerce->get('customers', $args);
            $all_customers = array_merge($all_customers, $customers);
        }
    } else {
        echo "No customers found.";
    }`

Comment: Thank you for this but this $customers = $woocommerce->get('customers', $args); is already returning an empty array even i have tried checking with condition its an empty array.

Comment: @SalmanKhanSohoo have you checked by defining this as variable `$all_customers = []; ` before the loop.

Comment: yes i have tried this as well, but the issue is this is returning an empty array $customers = $woocommerce->get('customers', $args); atleast this should give some data in response.